# Change IP with Python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize-python

Is is possible to actually fake your IP details via mechanize? But if it's not, for what is `br.set_proxies()` used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant' fake you IP address because IP is third layer and HTTP works on 7th layer.
So, it's imposible to send ip with non-your ip.

(you can set up second interface and IP address using iproute2 and set routing throught that interface, but it's not python/mechanize level. it's system level)

Answer (score 0):

You don't fake your IP details, set_proxy is to configure a HTTP proxy. You still need legitimate access to the IP.